# How to increase a number by 1 and add it to a string using Java each time the program runs

Tags: java, loops, automation, gmail

I'm trying to create a java program that will add a number to my email address every time is run. Example test+1@gmail.com next run: test+2@gmail.com and so on...
I'm trying to test login using one email address.
I want to increase the number each time the program is run by 1. What is the best loop to add here? For or while?

```
email1 = 'test';
email2 = '+';
email3 = '@gmail.com';
i=1
(loop)
i = i +1; # I know I need to add this in my loop. 

newEmail = (email1+email2+i+email3)
print newEmail
```

Any other suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by best loop and you mean `i = i + 1;` and not `i + i + 1`; and it is always depend on your use case.

Comment: You can use either for or while but for loop is more compact for this.

Comment: I don't no if I should be using for or while. I know that I need to add this to my loop: i = i + 1.

Comment: While and for loops are basically the same thing, logically, once you strip back the syntactic sugar.